# Hacer login en instagram antes de la solicitud

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Trato de mandar una petición a instagram, concretamente un fetch a esta url:

`https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1`

El problema es que `Instagram` bloquea el acceso porque no está `logueado` a la hora de hacer el `fetch`.
Intento crear un `loggin` con todas las cookies que me piden con un ejemplo que me pasaron, y me faltan dos cookies que no se dónde conseguir.

Hasta ahora tengo así la parte donde mando la información a nodejs:

```
function fileGetsContent(url, name){
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", `/user?name=${name}`, true);
                xhr.send()
            }
```

Y esto lo mando por url al nodejs, que es donde obtengo el nombre del usuario que quiero consultar si es publico o privado:

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res){
    let name = req.query.name;

    let csfr_cookie = 'csfrtoken=***';   //  !
    let ds_cookie = 'ds_user_id=***';   //  !
    let igdid_cookie = 'ig_did=***'; //  !
    let mid_cookie = 'mid=***';//    !
    let rur_cookie = 'rur=NAO';// !
    let sessionid_cookie = 'session_id=***';    //  !

    let domain_cookie = 'fbm_124024574287414=base_domain=.instagram.com';//   !
    let shbid_cookie = 'shbid=<valor>';// ?
    let shbts_cookie = 'shbts=<un flotante>';

//estas dos ultimas cookies no se de donde las puedo sacar
    
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        hostname: 'www.instagram.com',
        path: `/${name}/?__a=1`,
        port: 443,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'Accept-Encoding': '*',
          'Cookie': `${csfr_cookie},${ds_cookie},${igdid_cookie},${mid_cookie},${rur_cookie},${sessionid_cookie}`//y por ende, aqui me faltan esas dos cookies para poder hacer la peticion correctamenet
        }
      }

      fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${name}/?__a=1`, options)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
});
```

¿Cómo podría obtener la información que necesito?

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas está en [la documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#user-token-generator) del mismo API de ellos.

Comment: Si. Para consultar la información de un usuario tengo que tener primero su id de usuario, y no hay forma de conseguirlo si no es de esta forma XD. Si hubiera una forma en la docu, no preguntaría por aquí, creeme.

Comment: Hay mucha gente que no la lee y aún así postea; es reconfortante que tu sí jaja. Nunca he usado el API de instagram, entonces no creo poder ayudarte más que con ese comentario.